# converting linked list to single number

Tags: python, linked-list

I want to convert the linked list to a single number

for example [1,2,0] should convert to 120

and at the same time [-1,-2,0] should convert to -120

```
def list_to_number(head):
    count=0
    for i in head:
        if (head[i]<0):
            count+=1
        elif(head[i]>0):
            count=0
        elif (head[i]==0):
            continue
    if (count==0):
        n = list1(head)
        return n
    else:
        n = [abs(k) for k in head]
        n = list1(head)
        return -n
    pass

def list1(head):
    n= map(str,head)
    n = "".join(n)
    n = int(n)
    return n
```

Comment: And the problem is? Do you get incorrect results? An exception?

Comment: it is my code .is there any flaw in that please rectify the flaw

Comment: `elif (head[i]==0)` should be `else`; abs is done and lost in next line, beside it should be run for both (+-) cases; actually you only need if for return sign. Either way, your handling of negative numbers is strange - the whole number will take sign of last non-zero number - is this really what you intended?

Comment: what my intention is if there any negative number it is converting int o positive and later it is assigning negative sign.please give your code on this question @AdamJurczyk

Comment: I wont write it for you now, first fix your bugs and then we can talk about how it should look like.
You have some code, test it, look for few different lists and check if your code gives expected results. If not - go through the code for broken examples and try to figure out where is the bug.

Comment: What would the sign be with one negative sign, with two, with three, ... ?

Comment: There don't seem to be any linked lists involved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous what you are trying to do here, especially with the negative signs. Nevertheless, a good start would be to:

- Convert the ints to strings
- Concatenate the strings
- Turn the large string back into a number

For example:

```
def join(X):
    return int("".join(map(str,X)))

print join([1,2,0])          # 120
print join([0,2,1])          # 21
print join([9,4,2,4,230])    # 9424230
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def weird_conversion(digits):
...     return sum(n * 10**i for (i, n) in enumerate(reversed(digits)))
...
>>> weird_conversion([1, 2, 0])
120
>>> weird_conversion([-1, -2, 0])
-120
>>> weird_conversion([-1, 2, 0])
-80
>>> weird_conversion([1, -2, 0])
80
```

Comment: @user3329177, I sure can. Can you?